# How to install GUI on remote Linux server

Tags: linux, gui, vnc, rdp

I need to install GUI on a VPS Linux server. Service provider is Hetzner and Linux version is Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS I'm using MobaXterminal for X11 forwarding. And I'm using root credentials.

I have tried the following:

Gnome, KDE, xfce4, MATE desktop with port 22 and port 3389 They always show the same error:

> connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 sesman connect ok sending
> login info to session manager, please wait... login failed for display
> 0

VNC server installation I followed the guide on https://vitux.com/ubuntu-vnc-server/ but it showed an error like this.

> vncserver@1.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
> vncserver@1.service: Failed with result 'timeout'. Failed to start
> Remote desktop service (VNC).

Please don't write URL links to similar answers to my problem. I've tried more than 20 advises on the internet. None of them worked for me.

Please can anyone provide me a step-by-step solution?

Comment: Maybe you do not understand the idea. If you want to display on client machine graphical application you need X server on client machine.

Comment: Since a VPS is functioning like a dedicated server, you can install almost any software products you want.